# Removing space from Edit Text String

Tags: android, android-edittext

In my android app, I am getting the String from an Edit Text and using it as a parameter to call a web service and fetch JSON data.
Now, the method I use for getting the String value from Edit Text is like this :

```
final EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);

String k = edittext.getText().toString();
```

Now normally it works fine, but if we the text in Edit Text contains space then my app crashes.

for eg. - if someone types "food" in the Edit Text Box, then it's OK
but if somebody types "Indian food" it crashes.

How to remove spaces and get just the String ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Isn't that just Java?

```
String k = edittext.getText().toString().replace(" ", "");
```

Comment: yeah just java. I am sorry that was a little silly question.I could have just googled it.

Comment: single quotation mark`('')` is making error ..I use double quotation`("")` mark is working ..Ex : `String k = edittext.getText().toString().replace(" ", "");`

Answer (score 2):

try this...

```
final EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);

String k = edittext.getText().toString();

String newData  = k.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
```

and use "newData"

Comment: your solution seems perfect, but may I ask why the stress on "new"

Answer (score 1):

```
String email=recEmail.getText().toString().trim();
String password=recPassword.getText().toString().trim();
```

In the future, I highly recommend checking the Java String methods in the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html). It's a lifeline to getting the most out of your Java environment.

Answer (score 1):

Normally for web services, searching a query needs to be appended with '+' symbol.

e.g if we have `Indian Food`, it should be sent like `Indian+Food`

So, to get that we can use following...

```
String k = edittext.getText().toString().trim().replace(" ", "+");
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
String userName=username_edt.getText().toString().trim();
```

if use `trim()` it will remove spaces

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score -1):

You can easily remove all white spaces using something like [this](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.util.regex/RemDupSpace.html). But you'll face another serious problem if you just do that. For example if you have input

```
String input1 = "aa bb cc"; // output aabbcc
String input2 = "a abbcc";  // output aabbcc
String input3 = "aabb cc";  // output aabbcc
```

One solution will be to fix your application to accept white spaces in input string or use some other literal to replace the white spaces. If you are using only alphanumeric values you do something like this

```
String input1 = "aa bb cc"; // aa_bb_cc
String input2 = "a abbcc";  //a_abbcc
String input3 = "aabb cc";  //aabb_cc
```

And after all if you are don' caring about the loose of information you can use any approach you want.